# How to process withdrawal / deposits down the call stack?

Tags: solidity

If I have a payment processing contract which instantiates a contract that instantiates another contract, how do I securely process payments from within the most nested contract?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract MoneyVault {
    uint houseMoney; // contract value - deposits;
    mapping (address => uint) deposits;
    address[] games;

    constructor() {
        Game game = new Game();
        games.push(game);
    }
}

contract Game {
    address currentRound;

    function newRound() public {
        currentRound = new Round(msg.sender);
    }
}

contract Round {
    address player;
    function playerWins() public {
        // How to securely transfer money from houseMoney to my "deposits"?
    }

    constructor(address _player) {
        player = _player;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do this, but may I suggest changing the design altogether? it's wasteful (and costly) to deploy a contract per game round. All three contracts can be merged into a single contract. See this game as an example: https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-smart-contracts/tree/master/projects/predictions/v2